why when i'm attempting to create a new React app using the create-react-app command, but I'm encountering an error related to npm
that what is it look like :
PS C:\Users\layan> node -v
v21.7.3
PS C:\Users\layan> npx -v
10.5.0
PS C:\Users\layan> npx create-react-app projectone
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall lstat
npm ERR! path C:\Users\layan\AppData\Roaming\npm
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat 'C:\Users\layan\AppData\Roaming\npm'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\layan\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2024-04-20T15_02_05_667Z-debug-0.log

i try to reinstall node js many to with many version but it is still not work

Does C:\Users\layan\AppData\Roaming\npm exist and is it writable? v21.7.3 is the lastest version, have you tried down-grading to the last LTS version v20.12.2? Does the mentioned log file 2024-04-20T15_02_05_667Z-debug-0.log contain anything useful? You might get more info on the error if you set NODE_DEBUG env var with approriate values.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

the users in https://github.com/npm/cli/issues/7089 and https://github.com/npm/cli/issues/6971 and Why am I getting errors with npx? seams to be incountering the same issue so maybe check that out?
also have you tried
npm install npm -g

